# Samsung Auto sync personal data - Does syncing all at once use less data/less battery versus syncing small items every few minutes?

Tags: applications, samsung, sync, email, android-12

Does turning on auto-sync use a significant amount of mobile data and battery usage, or is it not as much as you'd think?

Let's say someone sent you 100 emails, would your phone use a fixed amount of data usage and battery to sync all those emails, or would it use slightly less data to sync that many emails like you were buying things cheap in bulk?

Would the same apply for battery usage, or would syncing a lot of emails at once use a lot more battery than syncing just one email?

Comment: In general a process that is executed less frequently should save battery as all the hardware components can stay longer in energy saving state. Additionally an intelligent scheduler could sync the data while charger is connected (not sure if this is done). How much the difference is is difficult to guess. The only way would be to monitor your device some weeks with enabled/disabled auto-sync and compare the results.

Comment: @Robert I see, I think the battery usage would make sense but I'm also wondering about the data used. Maybe it applies the same way and syncing a lot of emails at once might save more data than syncing multiple emails at different times?